# Common Aproaches to reduce code-overhead when using MapStruct in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, automapper, mapstruct

In c# the library https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html exists. It allows us to specify all Mappers/Mappings in one File - MapStruct forces me to create a new interface for every Mapper, which results in a lot of files i have to create and clutters the project.

Is there any way to write these mappers in a way that they are all in one file at least, or that they can be configured programatically?
I looked at alternatives like ModelMapper or JMaper, but they are not well maintained or way slower.

EDIT: i added sample code to illustrate the problem and highlight my issues with the current answer

```
public abstract class ProductMapper {
  public abstract ProductDto convertToDto(Product Product);

  public abstract Product convertToEntity(ProductDto checkoutProductDto);

  public abstract List<ProductDto> convertToDtos(List<Product> entities);

  public abstract List<Product> convertToEntities(List<ProductDto> dtos);
// below not working because of type erasure, so cant do it in the same file
  public abstract List<ProductOrderDetails> convertToEntities(List<ProductOrderDetailsDto> entities);
```

My project has hundreds of DTOs, most of them just requiring these 4 methods and no AfterMapping. Making these by hand is a giant waste of time, are there any better approaches?

Edit: i got a better answer from the mapstruct devs: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an abstract class with the 4 base methods, but with generic types seems like it would solve the issue. You'd still need to create the interface manually but the 4 methods would be already defined.

Here's an example in kotlin of what I mean.

These classes and mappers ( I've used kotlin only for convenience, but the mappers are still generated in java )  :

```kotlin
package mapper

import org.mapstruct.Mapper

abstract class EntityMapper<A, B>() {

    abstract fun toDto(a: A): B
    abstract fun toEntity(b: B): A
}

data class Device(val id: String)
data class DeviceDto(val id: String)

@Mapper
abstract class DeviceMapper : EntityMapper<Device, DeviceDto>()

data class OtherDevice(val id: String)
data class OtherDeviceDto(val id: String)

@Mapper
abstract class OtherDeviceMapper : EntityMapper<OtherDevice, OtherDeviceDto>()
```

Make mapstruct generate these 2 following mappers:

```java
@Component
public class DeviceMapperImpl extends DeviceMapper {

    @Override
    public DeviceDto toDto(Device a) {
        if ( a == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String id = null;

        id = a.getId();

        DeviceDto deviceDto = new DeviceDto( id );

        return deviceDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Device toEntity(DeviceDto b) {
        if ( b == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String id = null;

        id = b.getId();

        Device device = new Device( id );

        return device;
    }
}
```

And

```java
@Component
public class OtherDeviceMapperImpl extends OtherDeviceMapper {

    @Override
    public OtherDeviceDto toDto(OtherDevice a) {
        if ( a == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String id = null;

        id = a.getId();

        OtherDeviceDto otherDeviceDto = new OtherDeviceDto( id );

        return otherDeviceDto;
    }

    @Override
    public OtherDevice toEntity(OtherDeviceDto b) {
        if ( b == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String id = null;

        id = b.getId();

        OtherDevice otherDevice = new OtherDevice( id );

        return otherDevice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

MapStruct doesn't force you to create a new interface for every mapper. You can use one interface for multiple mappings. Here is the example I used in my project:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DeviceMapper {

    Device dtoToEntity(DeviceDto.CreateBody body);

    Manufacturer dtoToEntity(ManufacturerDto dto);
    ManufacturerDto entityToDto(Manufacturer entity);

    Platform dtoToEntity(PlatformDto.CreateBody body);
    PlatformDto.Response entityToDtoResponse(Platform platform);

    DeviceRole dtoToEntity(DeviceRoleDto dto);
    DeviceRoleDto entityToDtoResponse(DeviceRole entity);

    DeviceType dtoToEntity(DeviceTypeDto dto);
    DeviceTypeDto entityToDtoResponse(DeviceType entity);

}
```

Comment: I have attempted this approach, however its IMO unpractical.
Due to type erasure, using Lists with this is not possible.
This means different method names will be required, further complicating things that are already complex because in this case i would have to guess which Mapper has what methods/dtos inside

The only really good solution i can think of would be autogenerated Mappers that also generate the necessary 4 methods for one object each (entitydto,dtoentity and both with lists). I am doing this in a large project and the clutter of this is gigantic